# Selecting a schema to connect to when connecting over an ODBC connection in Excel's Power Query

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, m

So I have a fairly simple query (proof of concept) where I'm able to dynamically pull in data from a database depending on my Excel sheet inputs. For example:

```
let
    Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=Dev 2", "select * #(lf)from job_id JI#(lf)where JI.job_ID  = " & Text.From(GetNamedRange("SQLJobInstanceID")) & "#(lf)")
in
    Source
```

Hurray, it works! However, when I was setting up the connection, I needed to log in. Part of the login includes the schema that I wanted to connect to. `Username[Schema]` is how it's done. Now that I've connected, I'd like to select a different schema to connect to - but I'm not sure how I can either modify the schema, or log out and log back in.

(Also curious if the connection is storing my credentials, which would be problematic, or if other people would need to log in with their credentials)

I believe I can also edit which ODBC connection I'm using by editing the `"dsn=Dev 2"` portion of the code (Again, will probably turn it into a named range drop down menu.... the challenge becomes dynamically figuring out what ODBC options each user has and pulling those through...)

Thank you

Comment: Welp, turns out in Get Data -> Data Source Settings -> Edit Permissions -> Edit Credentials has what I need... now if only there was an easier way to edit them....

Comment: With regards to credentials, I believe they are stored locally on the office account for the user, not in the Excel file itself. Also as far as I am aware, there is no way to dynamically define credentials through PQ or through VBA interacting with PQ (from a couple things I've seen this was an intentional decision by Microsoft).

Comment: I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.connection which seems to suggest you can dynamically define the credentials, but it requires a bit of VBA to make it work. I'm seeing a userID, a password, and a DSN, (And with our setup the username also has the schema attached to it)

Comment: With regards to Connection objects and Power Query, those are actually what is used to link the results from Power Query to tables/data models in Excel. If you look at the details of a Connection object created when you setup a Query, you will see it has nothing to do with the data sources of the query, and is instead a SQL connection to retrieve the end result of the Query.

Comment: Really? Even though it explicitly says "This example supplies new ODBC connection information" - isn't that the source of the data for the query?

Comment: Yeah if you look at the connection you'll see it's just an OLE DB connection to retrieving the results from Power Query. Power Query has it's own mechanisms for connecting to data that are functionally separate from any connectors Excel may have. You have to remember that Power Query was primarily developed for Power BI and it's inclusion in Excel operates like an add-in, not an integrated piece.